# Custom django user registration

Tags: django

I am doing a user registration function, this is views

```
from django.http import HttpResponseGone    
from .forms import RegisterForms   
from django.shortcuts import render    
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_forms = RegisterForms(request.POST)
        if user_forms.is_valid():
            new_userform = user_forms.save(commit=False)
            new_userform.set_password(user_forms.cleaned_data['password'])
            new_userform.save()
            return HttpResponseGone('注册成功')
        else:
            return HttpResponseGone('注册失败')
    else:
        user_forms = RegisterForms()
        return render(request,'account/register.html',{'form':user_forms})
```

this is forms

```
from django import forms    
from django.contrib.auth.models import User    
class RegisterForms(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password',widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='password again',widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email')
    def clean_password2(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if cd['password'] != cd['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('密码输入不一致，请从新输入')
        else:
            return cd['password']
```

this is html

```
<p>欢迎注册</p>
<form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>username {{ form.username }}</p>
    <p>email {{ form.email }}</p>
    <p>password {{ form.password }}</p>
    <p>password again {{ form.password2 }}</p>
    <input type="submit" value="register">
</form>
```

I found that if I change the name of the clean_password2 method in the views file to clean_password, I can not get the value of password2 in the form

This is the wrong message[enter image description here][4]

My English is not very good I hope someone can help me  Thank Thank Thank

Comment: Don't post code as images. Include code as text in the question body.

Comment: May be you forgot to add fields into tuple                                            fields=('username','email','password','password2')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django import forms

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class RegisterForms(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password',widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='password again',widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email','password','password2')
    def clean(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if cd['password'] != cd['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('密码输入不一致，请从新输入')
        else:
            return cd
```

In short use clean method in such conditions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help